# Three loop diagram

Tags: diagrams, loops, feynmf

I want to make a three loop diagram such as the one on the left.
[image]

I use the following script

```
\fmfleft{i}\fmfright{o}

\fmf{boson}{i,v1}\fmf{boson}{v2,o}

\fmf{phantom,left,tension=0.1}{v1,v2,v1}\fmffreeze

\fmfipath{p[]}

\fmfiset{p1}{vpath (__v1, __v2)}

\fmfiset{p2}{vpath (__v2, __v1)}

\fmfi{plain}{subpath (0, 1)*length(p1) of p1}

\fmfi{plain}{subpath (0, 1)*length(p2) of p2}

\fmfipair{vn,vs}

\fmfiequ{vn}{point 0.3length(p1) of p1}

\fmfiequ{vs}{point 0.3length(p2) of p2}

\fmfi{gluon}{vn--vs}
```

Here is the result. [image]

However I don't know how to create another loop inside the existing one (M2 inside of M1 on the first picture).

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a proper answer because I'm no expert with `feynmp` (probably because I'm not a physicist) but if you know a little `metapost` you can cheat a bit by using the `curly` and `wiggly` macros from the `feynmp` package.  Here's one way to draw the picture the OP wanted.

```
input feynmp
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "ff.eps";

beginfig(1);

path inner_ring, outer_ring;
inner_ring = fullcircle scaled 50;
outer_ring = fullcircle scaled 120;

drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1bp);
drawarrow reverse outer_ring rotated -225;
drawarrow subpath (0,4) of inner_ring;
drawarrow subpath (4,8) of inner_ring;

drawoptions();
draw curly point 2 of outer_ring -- point 2 of inner_ring;
draw curly point 6 of inner_ring -- point 6 of outer_ring;

draw wiggly point 4 of outer_ring + 20 left -- point 4 of outer_ring;
draw wiggly point 0 of outer_ring -- point 0 of outer_ring + 20 right;

label.rt(btex $\rm M_1$ etex, point 1 of outer_ring);
label.rt(btex $\rm M_2$ etex, point 1 of inner_ring);

for p = 0, 2, 4, 6: fill fullcircle scaled 3bp shifted point p of outer_ring; endfor
for p = 2, 6:       fill fullcircle scaled 3bp shifted point p of inner_ring; endfor

endfig;
end.
```

[image]